# Encrypt json file and then decrypt the file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, encryption

Here am able to encrypt and decrypt the file properly, but after decrypt not able to read json key pair value in fluttet

Comment: share your code as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.